# What is the best way to run a circuit over a 3' concrete block wall (for a baseboard thermostat)?

Tags: electrical, conduit, concrete-block

I'm installing a Mysa wifi line voltage thermostat to control an electic baseboard heater mounted against a concrete block wall.

This is in a 2nd floor detached garage, and the 2 story structure was built into the grade, so the block wall extends up to half of the 2nd floor.

[image: Lower wall is drywall over concrete block, upper section is wood frame.]

Power comes through the floor. What is the **correct** way to get from the floor over this concrete wall?

EMT conduit and a surface mount box for the thermostat?
EMT conduit just over the block wall to junction box, then pass into wall cavity?
sealtight conduit?
BX Cable?

See below for the way the original electricians solved this problem previously for another circuit ran from the 2nd floor down to the first. They used sealtight conduit from wall box to a hole in the floor. (disregard the drywall work I'm doing here)

[image: previous electricians used sealtight conduit]

The baseboard has 2 extra knockouts I can use to pass the supply line from the floor up to the thermostat then back again to the connections, however they are at the back. The space between the wall and baseboard is only about 1" but I could install a low-profile BX cable 90-degree fitting, or add spacers to make more clearance between the wall and baseboard if needed.

[image: Baseboard showing 2 unused knockouts]

Comment: Both are safe and code compliant, AFAIK, but I prefer the EMT approach (certainly more secure from damage than those cheesy liquid tight non-metallic connectors are.) BX would also be fine. But aesthetics is very much opinion...which is not on topic here. Perhaps a hunk of raceway, though...

Comment: I forgot about raceway as an option. Hmm... thanks for the clarification that all options should work.

Comment: Please [edit] to remove the "aesthetics" portion of the question, as that's tempting to close for being "opinion" or "design" based. Otherwise, good question.

Comment: Additional pair of comments: straighten the bent fins before putting the cover back on, and seriously consider a mini-split (cost a lot more to buy, cost a lot less to run - mine work effectively to -15 °F, but that's a point you have to shop on given your local climate conditions.)

Comment: @enecrwal thanks for the tip for some reason I thought heat pumps required some specific amount of humidity but I may be thinking of the older technology.  Just spent some time researching these systems and I didn't realize they can be run in reverse for heating.  Winter lows in my area of Northern California (during the daytime) are only 20F, and typically high as 30F so seems like that wouldn't be an issue.  I'm investigating AC for the main house and will include this garage space in this process. Thanks!

Comment: With a low of 20 °F you'll have **many** options available (including the DIY mini-splits if you want to go that way - though I felt like the SEER/COP on those was not as good when I shopped, but then, when I shopped they also did not have a low that would work for my situation, while the "installer required" options did.) That may have changed, it's been a few years - and they certainly cost less. Mine mostly do heat, with a rare stretch of cooling.